# Hugo – How to add different class names based on counter

Tags: loops, templating, hugo

Using Hugo, I need add unique class names to the first few posts. How can this be done?

My code that's obviously not working…

```
// if the first post
{{ if eq .Site.GetPage 1 }}
    {{ $classname := "class-one" }}
// else the second post
{{ elseif eq .Site.GetPage 2 }}
    {{ $classname := "class-two" }}
// else the third post
{{ elseif eq .Site.GetPage 3 }}
    {{ $classname := "class-three" }}
{{ else }}
{{ end }}

<li class="{{ $classname }}">
    …
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's some more efficient way, but this works:

```
{{ $paginator := .Paginate (where .Data.Pages.ByDate.Reverse "Type" "post") }}

{{ range $index, $element := $paginator.Pages }}

{{ if (eq $index 0) }}
{{ $.Scratch.Set "classname" "class-one" }}
{{ else if (eq $index 1) }}
{{ $.Scratch.Set "classname" "class-two" }}
{{ else }}
{{ $.Scratch.Set "classname" "" }}
{{ end }}

<li class="{{ $.Scratch.Get "classname" | safeHTML }}">
    …
</li>

{{ end }}
```